Оптимизация SQL запроса на большом количестве данных в MySQL
покопался в коде, хочу SQL оптимизировать.
Почему-то если к SQL запросу добавить ORDER BY i.id DESC то время запроса увеличится с 0.0008 до 5 секунд, при том что i.id c AUTO_INCREMENT и PRIMARY
Как тогда ускорить SQL запрос?
SELECT
    s.img AS skin_img,
    s.title AS skin_title,
    s.name AS skin_name,
    s.rarity AS skin_rarity,
    c.img AS case_img,
    c.title AS case_title,
    c.name AS case_name,
    i.gotfrom
FROM inventory i
    JOIN skins s ON i.item_id = s.id
    LEFT JOIN cases c ON i.dropped_from_case = c.title
WHERE i.type = 'skin'
ORDER BY i.id DESC
LIMIT 100


В зависимости от статистики данных - использовать либо inventory (type, id, dropped_from_case, gotfrom), либо поменять местами 2 и 3 поля...
